# Bash xdotool writing output to variables

Tags: bash, shell, xdotool

Heyo guys. I am using bash script to get current location of my mouse, but I stuck with this. when I do:

```
xdotool getmouselocation
x:688 y:411 screen:0 window:98568199
```

I got my output as a string, I am kinda newbie. How can I get values of `x` and `y` into some variables, so I can use them further. Thank you.

Comment: You made _some_ effort in trying to get your requirement done? Even if its trivial it should be fine

Answer (score 1):

The x coordinate is the first word in the output (taking for granted that the space is the word separator).  y coordinate is the second one.  So:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
output=$(xdotool getmouselocation)
x=$(echo $output | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d":" -f2)
y=$(echo $output | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d":" -f2)

echo "X= $x"
echo "Y= $y"
```

The awk prints the word you asked for ($1 or $2) and cut gives you what follows the ':' character.